# Переключение между окнами в Qt версии 4.8

Tags: c++, qt

В общем сделал как в примере на сайте https://evileg.com/ru/post/112/.

Но  выпрыгивает две ошибки  (С2248, С2664).

Qt 4.8

Вот код form.h:

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Form();
signals:
    void firstWindow();  // Сигнал для первого окна на открытие
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Form *ui;
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <form.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    Form *sWindow;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

form.cpp

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Form::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    this->close();      // Закрываем окно
    emit firstWindow(); // И вызываем сигнал на открытие главного окна
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    sWindow = new Form();
    // подключаем к слоту запуска главного окна по кнопке во втором окне
    connect(sWindow, &Form::firstWindow, this, &MainWindow::show);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    sWindow->show();  // Показываем второе окно
    this->close();    // Закрываем основное окно
}
```

А вот результат

```
  F:\WORK\DIMA\qwestion38\mainwindow.cpp:12: ошибка: C2248:
  Form::firstWindow: невозможно обратиться к protected член,
  объявленному в классе "Form" F:\WORK\DIMA\qwestion38\form.h(18): см.
  объявление "Form::firstWindow" F:\WORK\DIMA\qwestion38\form.h(10): см.
  объявление "Form"




  F:\WORK\DIMA\qwestion38\mainwindow.cpp:12: ошибка: C2664: bool 
  QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const
  char *,Qt::ConnectionType): невозможно преобразовать параметр 2 из
  "void (__thiscall Form::* )(void)" в "const char *"
      Не существует контекста, в котором такое преобразование возможно
```

Answer (score 3):

старый Qt не поддерживает нового синтаксиса соединения. Поэтому, вместо

```
connect(sWindow, &Form::firstWindow, this, &MainWindow::show);
```

надо писать что то вида

```
connect(sWindow, SIGNAL(firstWindow()), this, SLOT(show()));
```

Это точно пофиксит первую ошибку и должно пофиксить вторую.